# How to make a signup view using Class based views in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

When I started to use Django, I was using FBVs ( Function Based Views ) for pretty much everything including signing up for new users.

But as I delved deep more into projects, I realized that Class-Based Views are usually better for large projects as they are more clean and maintainable but this is not to say that FBVs aren't.

Anyway, I migrated most of my whole project's views to Class-Based Views except for one that was a little confusing, the SignUpView.

Comment: https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-class-based-auth-views

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In order to make SignUpView in Django, you need to utilize `CreateView` and `SuccessMessageMixin` for creating new users as well as displaying a success message that confirms the account was created successfully.

Here's the code :

`views.py`:

```
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class SignUpView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
  template_name = 'users/register.html'
  success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
  form_class = UserRegisterForm
  success_message = "Your profile was created successfully"
```

and, the `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
  email = forms.EmailField()

  class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name']
```

Comment: In the views.py file, if I want to specifically display the username of the just created user, in the success_message, how do I do that?

Comment: I think you can try referencing the User model’s `username` attribute with f-strings in the success_message variable.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Django's CreateView for creating a new user object.

```
# accounts/views.py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic


class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'
```

For more info, check https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-signup-tutorial